# What does "RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback" mean? I know how to fix, looking for the meaning

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When I call a coroutine without awaiting, in addition to a message warning me I have not awaited the coroutine, I also get the following warning message:

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I know how to fix this i.e. by awaiting the coroutine (and I do see a lot of questions about this warning, but all the answers are how to fix it; my goal is to understand it; please don't mark my question as duplicate if possible :) ); in particular, what I'd really like to understand is:

- What is tracemalloc? How do I enable it?
- What is the object allocation traceback?
- How is it related to coroutines? and, in particular
- Why is there a warning suggesting to enable tracemalloc when I don't await a coroutine?

My goal in asking this is understanding the details and inner-workings of asyncio better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is tracemalloc? How do I enable it?

`tracemalloc` is a module that is used to debug memory allocation in Python.
You can enable it by setting `PYTHONTRACEMALLOC` environment variable to `1`.
Check the [Tracemalloc docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) for more info.

> What is the object allocation traceback?

It's a way how Python manages memory and allocates memory for its objects.

> Why is there a warning suggesting to enable tracemalloc when I don't await a coroutine?

I guess this is because memory is allocated and never used properly so we get loss of resources, i.e. a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! Is it the case that once I await the coroutine and it finishes, that is a signal to the garbage collector that it may clean up some memory that otherwise causes said leak?